# Reportlab: How to add uncertain contents using BaseDocTemplate?

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I want to add contents on first page. But the data is uncertain, contents must draw depend on the data.

I try to fix this problem by drawing twice, calculating and recording the contents, and it works well.
But it wastes time and ungainly.

Can I insert first page after completing drawing? Or other ways to fix this problem?

Sorry, I'm poor of English..

Comment: I don't entirely understand your question, but if you are trying to add a table of contents there is a build in way of doing that if you use Platypus with ReportLab.

Comment: Example, I try to draw a pdf. Data [{'china': content}, {'usa': content2}], and on first page, contents are China ------ page 1, usa------page 2. Because the content is uncertain, so usa maybe in page 2 or page 3 ... I should draw the contents on first page by calculating everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Platypus with ReportLab you can get a table of contents "for free": just see the ReportLab manual for details but you basically just add a `TableOfContents` to the list of `Flowables` for the document and you're done. Otherwise you'll have to figure out all the logic for building a table of contents yourself.